# File on php showing HTML document

Tags: files, php

Hy,

I'm getting an issue when I'm doing a `file` on some .php files on apache2 Vhost.
Here is the problem:

```
# file *.php
file1.php:    PHP script, UTF-8 Unicode text, with very long lines
file2.php:    PHP script, UTF-8 Unicode text, with very long lines
file3.php:    HTML document, UTF-8 Unicode text, with very long lines
```

Any ideas on why the system (RHEL) doesn't see file3.php as PHP script ?

```
# head file3.php 
<?
include("./some/files.php");

$var="";

$var = "select var, var from vars order by 2";
$var = var($var,$var);
while ($var = @var($var))
{ var($var) ;
  $var .= "\"".$var."\"," ;
```

I've changed `<?` to `<?php` but nothing has changed.

```
php -v
PHP 5.4.16 (cli)
```

Comment: Is it only the `file` output that bothers you? If this is not your *actual* issue, you should post a new question with a detailed explanation of your problem.

Comment: Yes it's just the output of `file` command that I don't understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `file` utility uses different heuristics to determine the file type. It may be the case that `file3.php` has more HTML-tags than the other two.

However, the output of the `file` utility does not influence your system's operation (unless you are parsing the output, of course).
In particular, it is not "your system (RHEL)" that treats this file as HTML.
If it is a valid PHP file, `php` will execute the script as it should - independent of what `file` says. (Try `php -l file3.php` for a syntax check.)

Answer (score -1):

Your server is not running your file as php script because you are using short tags in your php script i.e
`<? //php code
?>`
and in some php installation the short tags are default disabled.

So simply replace `<? ?>` tags with `<?php ?>` or enable the short tags from php configuration.

Comment: Quoting the Question, "I've changed <? to <?php but nothing has changed"